# Conditional Search Results

Tags: google-app-maker

I'm creating a 'Kiosk' where users can sign-in and out. 
I'm stuck on the sign-out component.

I'd like to have a table that only returns visitors that have not signed out after the end-user searches.

My search box has the following properties:

Value:

```
@datasource.query.filters.fullname._startsWith
```

On value change:

```
if (widget.value === null || (widget.value).length === 0){
    widget.datasource.unload();
} else {
    widget.datasource.load();
}
```

I'm new to this & JS as a whole. How can I filter the search to only contain users that have not signed out?

Comment: Which field from your database indicates that users have logged in/out? Are you maintaining something like this? In other words how can you tell how many visitors have signed in?

Comment: I have a boolean field called "signedout".

Comment: Before the `widget.datasource.load();` line add `widget.datasource.query.filters.signedout._equals = false;`

Comment: This worked. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Refer [this](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/datasources) in depth to gain more understanding appmaker datasources and filters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments you need to add `widget.datasource.query.filters.signedout._equals = false;` line before you load your data source. However you should make one more change while unloading.

Here's the full code.

```
if (widget.value === null || (widget.value).length === 0){
    widget.datasource.unload();
    widget.datasource.load();
} else {
    widget.datasource.unload();
    widget.datasource.query.filters.signedout._equals = false;
    widget.datasource.load();
}
```

Here `unload()` will unload previous data and `load()` will reload it. Now while reloading you can pass multiple filters so it reloads only filtered records.